# Conditional Behavior in project Reactor stack

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I need to create a method that gets data from external cache. If a data is found it does some processing otherwise it should do different processing.
The method should return Mono

```java
Mono<Void> myMethod() {
   return getDataFromCache()
             .flatMap(data -> processDataFromCache(data))
             .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> doSomethingElse()));
}
```

The issue I'm having is, because processDataFromCache(data) return type is Mono<Void>, the switchIfEmpty part is always executed.
Is there a way to do this differently?

Comment: How do you know if the data has been processed or not ?  Do you have any indicator that the data is or is not in cache ?

Comment: getDataFromCache() sends no onNext() signals if no data is there.

Comment: I do not have time to check, but for me, a `Mono<Void>` cannot emit "onNext" signal. Therefore, it always only emit completion, i.e. is always empty. If `processDataFromCache(data)` always completes, even if data is not present in cache, it will be difficult. The easiest way to fix this would be to make it return something (a boolean would be enough). Otherwise, you might solve it if you've got external / other api that can tell you if a data has been processed or is in cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot change the behavior of the `processDataFromCache` and `doSomethingElse` then you can connect them with some *fake* values coming after their successful execution:

```
Mono<Void> myMethod() {
   return getDataFromCache()
             .flatMap(data -> processDataFromCache(data).then("processed"))
             .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> doSomethingElse().then("new")))
             .then();
}
```